# Iterate through a 2d array replacing values of columns (make code generic)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I have a CODE 2 that I would like to make generic. CODE 2 takes 2d array columns as values: x1, x2, x3, x4 and R. And generates probabilities. I would like to create a code that doest this generic for 2d arrays with lots of columns.

In my CODE 1, I've successfully printed my 2d array columns as a 1d array using the first part of my code.

Then, I would like to take each one of my columns and replace them with x1, for example, in the following line: `double p1 = network.performQuery("P(+x1|+R)")`. So, as I have 4 columns, I want a loop that iterates for x1, x2, x3, x4. Notice my last column is named R.

I thought about this code but it's not working:

CODE 1

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  double  DATA[][] = { 

 // x1,x2,x3,x4,R                            
  { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // case 1 
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, // case 2 
  { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // case 3 
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // case 4 
  { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, // case 5 
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // case 6 
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // case 7 
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, // case 8 
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // case 9 
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, // case 10   
      };


for (int j = 0; j < DATA[0].length; j++) {
double[] cols = new double[DATA.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
        cols[i] = DATA[i][j];
    }

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cols)); //prints it right

MLDataSet data = new BasicMLDataSet(DATA,null);
BayesianNetwork network = new BayesianNetwork();
network.createEvent(cols); // in CODE 2, cols = x1 is written between quotation marks


//TRAINING PART

double p1 = network.performQuery("P(+" + cols +"|+R)");
//double p1 = network.performQuery("P(+x1|R)");
System.out.println("x1 probability : " + network.getEvent("" +  cols + "").getTable().findLine(1, new int[] {1}));
System.out.println("Calculated P(+R|+"  + cols+   "): " + p1);
//System.out.println("Calculated P(+R|+x1):" + p1);

}

}
```

CODE 2

```
double  DATA[][] = { 

 // x1,x2,x3,x4,R                            
  { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // case 1 
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, // case 2 
  { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // case 3 
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // case 4 
  { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, // case 5 
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // case 6 
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // case 7 
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, // case 8 
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // case 9 
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, // case 10   
      };

    MLDataSet data = new BasicMLDataSet(DATA,null);
    BayesianNetwork network = new BayesianNetwork();
    network.createEvent("x1"); 
    network.createEvent("x2");
    network.createEvent("x3");
    network.createEvent("x4");
    network.createEvent("R");
    network.finalizeStructure();

    //TRAINING PART    
    TrainBayesian train = new TrainBayesian(network,data,10);
    train.setInitNetwork(BayesianInit.InitEmpty);
    while(!train.isTrainingDone()) { 

            train.iteration();

            }



    double p1 = network.performQuery("P(+x1|+R)"); 
    double p2 = network.performQuery("P(+x2|+R)"); 
    double p3 = network.performQuery("P(+x3|+R)"); 
    double p4 = network.performQuery("P(+x4|+R)"); 

 System.out.println("x1 probability : " + network.getEvent("x1").getTable().findLine(1, new int[] {1}));
 System.out.println("x2 probability : " + network.getEvent("x2").getTable().findLine(1, new int[] {1}));
 System.out.println("x3 probability : " + network.getEvent("x3").getTable().findLine(1, new int[] {1}));
 System.out.println("x4 probability : " + network.getEvent("x4").getTable().findLine(1, new int[] {1}));
 System.out.println("R probability : " + network.getEvent("R").getTable().findLine(1, new int[] {1}));


 System.out.println("Calculated P(+R|+x1): " + p1);
 System.out.println("Calculated P(+R|+x2): " + p3);
 System.out.println("Calculated P(+R|+x3): " + p4);
 System.out.println("Calculated P(+R|+x4): " + p5);
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: Also, isn't the array *column* same as *DATA*. and why are you using a nested loop when only one loop was sufficient. Please review your question again, it's very unclear, also, your code doesn't show us the  declaration *column*, and you are copying *DATA* into it, which is an empty array itself.

Comment: @GBlodgett Java

Comment: @BananaSenpai I've edited my question, I hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: If I get the idea right, you want to put a `list of all x1` in place of `cols` during j=0 iteration in the  `network.performQuery("P(+" + cols +"|+R)");`? And if so, what format do you want it in? like should it be like `1 1 0 1 0 ...` or `1, 1, 0, ...` or `[1, 1, 0, ...]`?

Comment: @BananaSenpai I edited my code again to make my question simpler. Basically, all I want to do is to make CODE 2 generic. For that reason, I thought about creating a loop saving the arrays of the columns and replacing them in the commented lines. That way I won't have to write 5 times each line for each column.